# How to implement Proxy in ES5

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Lets have the following snippet:

```
var obj = {};
obj.doSomething = function(){
    console.log("Hello from obj");
}
```

I would like to create a proxy for this object and each time any method from `obj` is called, to do something else and then call the actual `obj` method.
Lets say I would like the proxy to print message "Calling [*methodname*] from object [*object*]"

Example:

```
obj.doSomething();
```

Output:

```
Calling [doSomething] method from object [obj].
Hello from obj
```

How to implement this in `ES5`?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check [this article about the try-catch proxy](https://tugayilik.medium.com/error-handling-via-try-catch-proxy-in-javascript-54116dbf783f), modify the line before `apply()` with your own needs as well as syntax to ES5

Answer (score -1):

You can use the builtin JavaScript Proxy object, like so:

```js
var obj = {};
obj.doSomething = function(){
    console.log("Hello from obj");
}

const handler = {
  get: function(target, prop) {
    console.log(`Calling [${prop}] from object [${target}]`);
    target[prop]();
  }
};

const proxy = new Proxy(obj, handler);
proxy.doSomething
```

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

In ES5 it is more complicated, but you can do the following:

```js
var obj = {};
obj.doSomething = function(){
    console.log("Hello from obj");
}




function Proxy(target) {
  var handler = function(prop) {
    return function() {
      console.log("Calling [" + prop + "] from object [" + target + "]");
      target[prop]();
    }
  }
  
  var p = {};
  var keys = Object.keys(target);
  for(var i=0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    p[key] = handler(key);
  }

  return p;
}


var proxy = new Proxy(obj);
proxy.doSomething()
```

Comment: this is not supported in `ES5`